# how to parse only domain name

Tags: java

I want to parse only domain name in JAVA.
For example,

```
http://facebook.com/bartsf
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Shine-Communications/169790283042195
http://graph.facebook.com/100002306245454/picture?width=150&height=150
http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=37.78353+-122.39579
http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&amp;q=http://www.onlinehaendler-news.de/interviews/1303-abba24-im-spagat-zwischen-haendler-und-kaeuferinteressen.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cad=CAEQARgAIAAoATABOAFAnqSQjwVIAVAAWABiAmRl&amp;cd=xa_cHWHNG70&amp;usg=AFQjCNFMgnkzqN0fNKMFKz1NTKK1n9Gg9A
```

Here is my code I am writing map reduce code.

```
 String[] whiteList={"www.facebook.com","www.google.com"};
 UrlValidator urlValidator=new UrlValidator(schemes);
 Readfile line by line

for line in file
{
            String sCurrentLine=line;
            if(sCurrentLine.length()>=3)
            {
                String tempString=sCurrentLine.substring(0,3);

                if(!tempString.equals("192") && !tempString.equals("172") && !tempString.equals("10."))
                {

                    sCurrentLine="http://"+sCurrentLine;
                    if(urlValidator.isValid(sCurrentLine))//domain filter should be here
                    {
                           System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                    }
                }
                tempString="";
            }
 }
```

I want to filter if the domain name is either facebook.com or google.com which all urls above get filtered out.

Comment: The `String` class has utility methods for that.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried. Ideally String class contains() method should help you

Comment: Read up on the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Specifically, `substring(int)` and `substring(int, int)`

Comment: One downvote with comment should be enough, I am concerned about intolerance of community towards bad questions and seeing so many down votes.  I am upvoting the question as it is interesting problem and I don't think String class' methods are the right solution

Comment: @WandMaker I agree that string methods are the wrong solution, but it's really not an interesting problem at all.

Comment: sorry guys I will update my code give me sec

Answer (score 8):

Use [`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) to parse strings as URIs. There's no need to reinvent the wheel here.

```
URI foo = new URI("http://facebook.com/bartsf");
String host = foo.getHost(); // "facebook.com"
```

Comment: Yo would need to add some exception handling here or have the method declare a checked exception.

Comment: Well, this answer is not 100% correct as it does not return "facebook.com" for the input with "www" which is what the person who asked the question wanted.

Comment: What advantage do you see in `URI` over `URL`?

Comment: @Lee it returns "www.facebook.com", which means some more effort is needed to extract the "facebook.com" out of it

Comment: @LeeMeador URL makes network calls for some operations (!!!). URI does not. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8953266/139010

Comment: I wouldn't think `getHost()` would though.

Comment: @LeeMeador the JavaDoc implies that it's just `URL#equals()` and `URL#hashCode()`. You're correct that `getHost()` does not. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/URL.java.html#791

Comment: if url domain starts like this http://Myhub.Corp.google.com/Person.apx?accountname=xxx\asvel URI occurs an exception error

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the URL class:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.facebook.com/pages/Shine-Communications/169790283042195");
String host = url.getHost();
// 'indexOf' is required since the root domain is all you care about. This handles
//  bob.facebook.com as well as facebook.com 
if (host.indexOf("facebook.com") >= 0 || host.indexOf("google.com") >= 0) {
    ... got one of those ...
} else {
    ... got something else ...
}
```

You have to add some `try ... catch` stuff to handle passing strings to the URL constructor that might not be a URL at all.

Also, be warned that this probably won't do exactly what you want if you pass it a  `file://` or a `mailto:` if that's a problem.

The biggest possible problem I have seen using this class is that nowhere in the javadocs does it define all the terms. For example, what is the path? It's returned by the method `getPath()` which has javadoc saying "Gets the path part of this URL." and you may wonder what exactly that includes. I wondered whether the last part of the URL, before the `?` or `#` if any, is included. (The answer is no. It just goes up to the last slash before the `?` or `#` or the end of the URL.)

**Continue as question expanded**

I don't like this line:

```
String tempString=sCurrentLine.substring(0,3);
if (!tempString.equals("192") && !tempString.equals("172") && !tempString.equals("10."))
```

But I do like this:

```
if(!sCurrentLine.startsWith("192.168.") && !sCurrentLine.beginsWith("172.") && !sCurrentLine.startsWith("10."))
```

I suspect it will work better if your whitelist just has 'facebook.com' and 'google.com' as the 'www' isn't so important and there are many subdomains for both companies.

The code above will go in your `UrlValidator` class.

Comment: Why `#indexOf` and not `#contains()`?

Comment: `contains` appeared in Java 5. `indexOf` is older and is matched with `lastIndexOf`. I like that. But `contains` returns a boolean so you don't have to compare it to zero. You could also use `matches` with a regex. I doubt, in this case, that it matters much.

Comment: This is complete answer, my upvote goes for this one

Comment: Java 5 is _ancient._ I see no reason to make choices based on what's available only in Java 4. Do you use generics? Guess what: Java 5.

Comment: @MattBall Pretty tacky comment. I'm not sure you understood what I answered.